# Implementing random partition point in partition function with pointers

Tags: c++

I'm trying to convert my partition function shown below from choosing the second last element as the partition to a random element. My original idea was to use the rand function something along the lines of

```
int *pivot = rand() % last;
```

However i've realised this wont work trying to parse an integer to a pointer integer. Is there any way i can get around this issue.

```
int *partition(int *first, int *last)
{

    int *pivot = last - 1;
    int *i = first;
    int *j = last - 1;
    for (;;)
    {
        while (comp_less(*i, *pivot) && i < last)
        {
            ++i;
        }
        while (*j >= *pivot && j > first)
        {
            --j;
        }
        if (i >= j)
            break;

        swap(*i, *j);
    }
    swap(*(last - 1), *i);
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pick a *distance* in the range [0, `std::distance(first, last)`), and add that to `first`.

Note that `rand` produces low quality pseudorandom numbers, and `rand() % N` does not uniformly pick numbers.

```
int * random_pivot(int * first, int * last)
{
    thread_local std::mt19937 random_engine(std::random_device{}());

    std::uniform_int_distribution<std::ptrdiff_t> range(0, std::distance(first, last) - 1);
    return first + range(random_engine);
}
```

If you are using random choices elsewhere, it would be better to pass `random_engine` in by reference, and only initialise one (per-thread) `std::mt19937`.